# Why is my NTP time sync root dispersion degrading over time?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ntp, ntpd

I have a test network setup with a Mikrotik router with a 4G/LTE internet connection, connected to one Raspberry Pi via Ethernet cable, and to 30 more Raspberry Pis via wifi.

I have set up NTP with the aim of minimising clock drift between the Raspberry Pi nodes, so that I can get good latency measurement results when running `iperf` and `netperf`. I am more interested in having the Raspberry Pi fleet *agree with each other* about the time than I am in their being *absolutely correct*, since the whole point of the exercise is to provide good latency data for wifi performance testing.

To ensure that all the Raspberry Pi nodes have access to a single common time source and minimise the potential impact of jitter and latency in the 4G/LTE uplink, I've configured the Mikrotik router as an NTP client to multiple internet time sources:

- `tic.ntp.telstra.net`
- `toc.ntp.telstra.net`
- `0.au.pool.ntp.org`
- `1.au.pool.ntp.org`
- `2.au.pool.ntp.org`
- `3.au.pool.ntp.org`

And it's configured as an NTP server to the local LAN (supporting unicast mode only).

The Mikrotik appears to be synchronising happily to the internet servers, with perfectly reasonable timing characteristics (by LTE standards):

Mikrotik NTP client status:

```
         enabled: yes
            mode: unicast
         servers: tic.ntp.telstra.net,toc.ntp.telstra.net,0.au.pool.ntp.org,1.au.pool.ntp.org,2.au.p
                  3.au.pool.ntp.org
      freq-drift: 3.611 PPM
          status: synchronized
   synced-server: toc.ntp.telstra.net
  synced-stratum: 2
   system-offset: -0.972 ms
```

Mikrotik NTP peer timing data:

```
type="ucast-client" address=203.14.0.250 refid="203.36.227.3" stratum=2 hpoll=10 ppoll=10 root-delay=55.221 ms 
   root-disp=0.885 ms offset=11.512 ms delay=55.956 ms disp=40.266 ms jitter=49.287 ms 

 type="ucast-client" address=27.124.125.250 refid="162.159.200.1" stratum=4 hpoll=10 ppoll=10 root-delay=3.692 ms 
   root-disp=2.838 ms offset=-5.166 ms delay=22.56 ms disp=0.119 ms jitter=15.666 ms 

 type="ucast-client" address=139.99.222.72 refid="17.253.66.253" stratum=2 hpoll=10 ppoll=10 root-delay=0.305 ms 
   root-disp=1.113 ms offset=-3.321 ms delay=74.975 ms disp=0.173 ms jitter=14.038 ms 

 type="ucast-client" address=13.55.50.68 refid="203.206.205.83" stratum=3 hpoll=10 ppoll=10 root-delay=31.066 ms 
   root-disp=52.902 ms offset=-3.031 ms delay=81.468 ms disp=0.184 ms jitter=13.174 ms 

 type="ucast-client" address=194.0.5.123 refid="8.145.32.135" stratum=2 hpoll=10 ppoll=10 root-delay=27.084 ms 
   root-disp=33.615 ms offset=-0.383 ms delay=79.435 ms disp=0.083 ms jitter=12.289 ms 

 type="ucast-client" address=203.14.0.251 refid="58.163.113.212" stratum=2 hpoll=10 ppoll=10 root-delay=38.833 ms 
   root-disp=2.258 ms offset=0.913 ms delay=34.001 ms disp=0.157 ms jitter=10.431 ms
```

The 31 Raspberry Pis are all running Raspberry Pi OS Lite (bullseye) 64-bit edition. I have installed `ntpd` and `ntpstat` on them, via standard apt packages. `ntpd` has replaced and masked `systemd-timesyncd`. The Pi NTP clients are configured to use the NTP server running on the Mikrotik as their sole time source.

Running `ntpq -pn` on the Raspberry Pis returns reasonable results.

On the node which is directly wired to the Mikrotik:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*10.3.0.126      203.14.0.251     3 u   48  128  377    0.506   +0.088   0.232
```

On a representative wifi node the delay and jitter are a few ms higher:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*10.3.0.126      203.14.0.251     3 u   76  128  377    1.541   -1.230   2.011
```

Yet, when I run `ntpstat` on the wired Raspberry Pi, I'm told that the time synchronisation quality is only good to 70 ms, and it's getting worse over time:

```
synchronised to NTP server (10.3.0.126) at stratum 4
   time correct to within 70 ms
   polling server every 128 s
```

This "time correct to" value is calculated from root dispersion and root delay. When I run `ntpq -c rv` repeatedly over the course of a few minutes, the `rootdisp` value is monotonically increasing.

```
pi@wired:~ $ ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p15@1.3728-o Wed Sep 23 11:46:38 UTC 2020 (1)",
processor="aarch64", system="Linux/5.10.92-v8+", leap=00, stratum=4,
precision=-22, rootdelay=73.314, rootdisp=32.686, refid=10.3.0.126,
reftime=e5c848b0.ab2d24bc  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:24:32.668,
clock=e5c84927.24f1e0bd  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:26:31.144, peer=41018, tc=7,
mintc=3, offset=-0.165471, frequency=-16.004, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=2.031, clk_wander=0.093

pi@wired:~ $ ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p15@1.3728-o Wed Sep 23 11:46:38 UTC 2020 (1)",
processor="aarch64", system="Linux/5.10.92-v8+", leap=00, stratum=4,
precision=-22, rootdelay=73.314, rootdisp=32.896, refid=10.3.0.126,
reftime=e5c848b0.ab2d24bc  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:24:32.668,
clock=e5c84934.f6a1b6af  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:26:44.963, peer=41018, tc=7,
mintc=3, offset=-0.165471, frequency=-16.004, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=2.031, clk_wander=0.093

pi@wired:~ $ ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p15@1.3728-o Wed Sep 23 11:46:38 UTC 2020 (1)",
processor="aarch64", system="Linux/5.10.92-v8+", leap=00, stratum=4,
precision=-22, rootdelay=73.314, rootdisp=37.906, refid=10.3.0.126,
reftime=e5c848b0.ab2d24bc  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:24:32.668,
clock=e5c84a83.a3e47e0e  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:32:19.640, peer=41018, tc=7,
mintc=3, offset=-0.165471, frequency=-16.004, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=2.031, clk_wander=0.093

pi@wired:~ $ ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p15@1.3728-o Wed Sep 23 11:46:38 UTC 2020 (1)",
processor="aarch64", system="Linux/5.10.92-v8+", leap=00, stratum=4,
precision=-22, rootdelay=73.314, rootdisp=51.003, refid=10.3.0.126,
reftime=e5c84c4e.ab29eed3  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:39:58.668,
clock=e5c84d42.f35d7000  Tue, Mar  1 2022 15:44:02.950, peer=41018, tc=7,
mintc=3, offset=-0.714738, frequency=-16.162, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=1.910, clk_wander=0.103
```

What could be causing the root dispersion to increase over time, and how do I fix it?

Since I don't actually care about absolute time accuracy very much, only node-to-node errors, can I just ignore the root dispersion and root delay (and hence the "accuracy" reported by `ntpstat`) and rely entirely on the Raspberry Pi-to-Mikrotik dispersion/delay/offset metrics?

Should I be changing the NTP architecture of this test setup somehow, to improve the synchronisation?

Comment: I have looked at this related question (https://serverfault.com/questions/184257/seemingly-poor-quality-of-ntp-time-synchronization-using-a-gps-clock), but that person was not experiencing a root dispersion that grew over time, or at least not at anything like the rate I'm seeing.

Comment: It’s just a test bench, so I’m not too concerned about the single point of failure at the moment. Besides, the Mikrotik is also the wifi AP and the Ethernet router, so the whole thing depends on it anyway.